# Spring Boot run java: java.lang.NullPointerException without error description, intellij Mac OS Catalina

Tags: java, macos, spring-boot, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception

I am trying to start a spring boot application on IntelliJ. I have two error in the console of type **NullPointerException without additional description**. I don't know where the problem might be.
Please help me!

This are the stack trace :

```
Executing pre-compile tasks...
Loading Ant Configuration...
Running Ant Tasks...
Running 'before' tasks
Checking sources
Copying resources... [xxx-xxx-xxx]
Checking dependencies... [xxx-xxx-xxx]
Dependency analysis found 0 affected files
Updating dependency information... [xxx-xxx-xxx]
Parsing java... [xxx-xxx-xxx]
java: Multiple elements named 'javax.annotation.Generated' in modules 'java.base, unnamed module, jdk.management.jfr, java.management, jdk.jfr, jdk.management, jdk.scripting.nashorn, java.scripting, java.logging, jdk.dynalink, javafx.web, javafx.base, java.desktop, java.datatransfer, java.xml, java.prefs, javafx.media, javafx.graphics, jdk.jsobject, javafx.controls, jdk.xml.dom, javafx.fxml, jdk.management.resource, java.instrument, jdk.security.auth, java.security.jgss, java.naming, java.security.sasl, jdk.jdi, jdk.attach, jdk.jdwp.agent, jdk.net, jdk.packager.services, jdk.jshell, jdk.compiler, java.compiler, jdk.security.jgss, jdk.jconsole, jdk.management.agent, java.management.rmi, java.rmi, jdk.accessibility, jdk.httpserver, jdk.sctp, javafx.swing, jdk.jartool, jdk.management.cmm, jdk.javadoc, jdk.unsupported, java.se, java.sql.rowset, java.sql, java.xml.crypto' were found by javax.lang.model.util.Elements.getTypeElement.
java: Multiple elements named 'javax.annotation.processing.Generated' in modules 'java.base, java.compiler, jdk.management.jfr, java.management, jdk.jfr, jdk.management, jdk.scripting.nashorn, java.scripting, java.logging, jdk.dynalink, javafx.web, javafx.base, java.desktop, java.datatransfer, java.xml, java.prefs, javafx.media, javafx.graphics, jdk.jsobject, javafx.controls, jdk.xml.dom, javafx.fxml, jdk.management.resource, java.instrument, jdk.security.auth, java.security.jgss, java.naming, java.security.sasl, jdk.jdi, jdk.attach, jdk.jdwp.agent, jdk.net, jdk.packager.services, jdk.security.jgss, jdk.jconsole, jdk.management.agent, java.management.rmi, java.rmi, jdk.accessibility, jdk.httpserver, jdk.sctp, javafx.swing, jdk.jartool, jdk.management.cmm, jdk.unsupported, java.sql.rowset, java.sql, java.xml.crypto' were found by javax.lang.model.util.Elements.getTypeElement.
java: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 5.4.2.Final
java: java.lang.NullPointerException
java: java.lang.NullPointerException
Dependency analysis found 0 affected files
javac 11.0.8 was used to compile java sources
Finished, saving caches...
Executing post-compile tasks...
Loading Ant Configuration...
Running Ant Tasks...
Synchronizing output directories...
11/26/20, 22:19 - Build completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 4 s 916 ms
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_SnlUKv9Tv6eQ2efjqh9oi9SXp_MUfoO/view?usp=sharing (Output console capture)

Comment: *"as you can see in the runtime console"* --- Nope, I can't see that. I can't see any runtime console at all.

Comment: Please paste the whole error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I was using java 9 which was incompatible with a dependency. I switched to Java 11